# Access Rules still redirects with Allow with parameters

Tags: php, yii, authorization

I have a SiteController and created an action named `actionForgotpassword`.

The idea is to make a recover password token so when the user clicks a link in his email inbox after he chose to recover his password, the applicaton can verify its authenticity and allow/not allow his password to be changed.
The link is something like:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php?r=site/forgotpassword?token=3dd0e0(..)16712dac3 
*localhost for testing locally, not in production
```

And I have these access rules in the Sites Controller:

```
 public function accessRules()
        {
            return array(
              array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('recover', 'forgotpassword', 'login'),
                'users'=>array('?'),
              ),
              array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('index', 'logout'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
              ),
              array('deny',
                 'users'=>array('*'),
              )

            );
        }
```

**My issue is:**

When I access the page like `localhost/project/index.php?r=site/forgotpassword` everything is OK but when I click the email link and the URL is like:

```
localhost/project/index.php?r=site/forgotpassword?token=3dd0e0(..)16712dac3
```

I get redirected to the projects Index (in this case the site/login action).

Why is this adopting this bahavior with parameters in the URL?
Do I need to specify anything else in the accessRules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `?` in your reset URL. I assume that you somehow manually created your URL. You should use `createUrl()` or probably better [`createAbsoluteUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createAbsoluteUrl-detail) instead:

```
$url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/forgotpassword', array(
    'token' => $token,
));
```

Comment: I forgot the yii routing already put an '?' in it's own URL. I should try and turning on my brain next time -_-'. Thank you Michael.